# Developing app works only in specific location

Tags: android, google-maps, security

I need to build an Android app that works only on my country for security reasons.
Is there a possible way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

1. The Play Store allows you to make your app available only in
   specific regions, but the app can be pulled from a device and posted
   / installed by anyone.
2. You can check the device's locale, but of course the user can change
   that.
3. You could get the device's IP address and map it to a region, but this isn't 100% accurate and can be spoofed.
4. Check the country code on mobile number and check whether the device
   is roaming (credit to @atayenel).

(4) sounds pretty solid. I'm however not qualified to comment on ways that could be spoofed.

You should comment on your requirements. If they are "absolutely cannot ever be used outside of the specified region", the only way to accomplish that would be to have the user authenticate (strongly) to an external account that employs some sort of trusted address verification mechanism.

If the requirements are best-effort prevention of use outside the specified region, I think you can employ some or all of the above.

Comment: 4. Check the country code on mobile number and check whether the device is roaming.

Comment: I'll not uploaded it in the store, so I don't have problems in this. But I don't want any one who  already  have  the app installed to open it outside the country